# How to convert stereo to right-channel mono on Windows 8?

Tags: audio, headphones, stereo, mono

I'm deaf on left side and I only can hear on right side. I have problems with videos that output in left channel or stereo, making it very difficult to hear.

I discovered that I couldn't convert all sounds, like from YouTube (rather than VLC with mono option) and I tried to look up how to make my right earphone function as mono, on right side.

I found this [stereo-to-mono plug on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RCZ14U) but they reported that this plug converted both channels to left channel mono. The meaning is sound will only come out in left ear instead of right ear, so this won't work for me because I only can hear in right ear.

Which device should I buy or do to convert stereo to right-sided mono?

Comment: I have a stereo to mono plug that looks just like that, but outputs the "mixed-down" mono sound to both ears. So I guess that's what you'd need...See this article, I think it describes your exact situation: https://www.cnet.com/news/making-headphones-mono/

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are very lucky your audio driver has it built-in:
   Right click the speaker>playback devices>speakers & headphones (or the default playback device)>properties>levels>mono mix. See pic [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-do-i-force-windows-8-to-output-in-mono-audio/53d09e95-6db1-4b2b-8de9-4717e61b3dd9)
2. Another option is to use some software that allows mix of audio outputs like:

   - [Voice Meeter](http://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm#DownloadVoicemeeter)
   - [SRS Audio Sandbox (shareware, recommended in the link from 1)](https://srs-audio-sandbox.en.softonic.com/)